# Append content to Toolsipter tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

In the below example I'm trying to make it so that when you click the "hello" button and then the "goodbye" button tooltipster will display a a popup that says "hello", "goodbye". However it seems that the way this is resolving will just show "hello" or "goodbye" twice. Does anyone know if this is somehow supported in tooltipster or am I going to have to insert html into the elements directly?

```js
$(function() {
  let tooltip = $("#tooltipster");
  tooltip.tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    side: 'right',
    contentAsHTML: true,
    interactive: true,
    functionFormat: function(instance, helper, content) {
      if (instance.status().open) {
        return instance.content() + "<br>" + content;
      } else {
        return content;
      }
    }
  });
  $("#add1").on("click", function() {
    tooltip.tooltipster('instance').content("hello").open();
  });
  $("#add2").on("click", function() {
    tooltip.tooltipster('instance').content("goodbye").open();
  });
})
```

```css
.tooltipster-fall,.tooltipster-grow.tooltipster-show{-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1);-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-ms-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-base{display:flex;pointer-events:none;position:absolute}.tooltipster-box{flex:1 1 auto}.tooltipster-content{box-sizing:border-box;max-height:100%;max-width:100%;overflow:auto}.tooltipster-ruler{bottom:0;left:0;overflow:hidden;position:fixed;right:0;top:0;visibility:hidden}.tooltipster-fade{opacity:0;-webkit-transition-property:opacity;-moz-transition-property:opacity;-o-transition-property:opacity;-ms-transition-property:opacity;transition-property:opacity}.tooltipster-fade.tooltipster-show{opacity:1}.tooltipster-grow{-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);-moz-transform:scale(0,0);-o-transform:scale(0,0);-ms-transform:scale(0,0);transform:scale(0,0);-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform;transition-property:transform;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}.tooltipster-grow.tooltipster-show{-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);-moz-transform:scale(1,1);-o-transform:scale(1,1);-ms-transform:scale(1,1);transform:scale(1,1);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-swing{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:rotateZ(4deg);-moz-transform:rotateZ(4deg);-o-transform:rotateZ(4deg);-ms-transform:rotateZ(4deg);transform:rotateZ(4deg);-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform,opacity;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform;transition-property:transform}.tooltipster-swing.tooltipster-show{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:rotateZ(0);-moz-transform:rotateZ(0);-o-transform:rotateZ(0);-ms-transform:rotateZ(0);transform:rotateZ(0);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,1);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);-ms-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4)}.tooltipster-fall{-webkit-transition-property:top;-moz-transition-property:top;-o-transition-property:top;-ms-transition-property:top;transition-property:top;-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-fall.tooltipster-initial{top:0!important}.tooltipster-fall.tooltipster-dying{-webkit-transition-property:all;-moz-transition-property:all;-o-transition-property:all;-ms-transition-property:all;transition-property:all;top:0!important;opacity:0}.tooltipster-slide{-webkit-transition-property:left;-moz-transition-property:left;-o-transition-property:left;-ms-transition-property:left;transition-property:left;-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-ms-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-slide.tooltipster-initial{left:-40px!important}.tooltipster-slide.tooltipster-dying{-webkit-transition-property:all;-moz-transition-property:all;-o-transition-property:all;-ms-transition-property:all;transition-property:all;left:0!important;opacity:0}@keyframes tooltipster-fading{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}.tooltipster-update-fade{animation:tooltipster-fading .4s}@keyframes tooltipster-rotating{25%{transform:rotate(-2deg)}75%{transform:rotate(2deg)}100%{transform:rotate(0)}}.tooltipster-update-rotate{animation:tooltipster-rotating .6s}@keyframes tooltipster-scaling{50%{transform:scale(1.1)}100%{transform:scale(1)}}.tooltipster-update-scale{animation:tooltipster-scaling .6s}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-box{background:#565656;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:4px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-box{margin-top:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-box{margin-right:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-box{margin-left:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-box{margin-bottom:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-content{color:#fff;line-height:18px;padding:6px 14px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow{overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow{height:10px;margin-left:-10px;top:0;width:20px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow{height:20px;margin-top:-10px;right:0;top:0;width:10px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow{height:20px;margin-top:-10px;left:0;top:0;width:10px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow{bottom:0;height:10px;margin-left:-10px;width:20px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-background,.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-border{height:0;position:absolute;width:0}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-background{border:10px solid transparent}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-bottom-color:#565656;left:0;top:3px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-left-color:#565656;left:-3px;top:0}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-right-color:#565656;left:3px;top:0}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-top-color:#565656;left:0;top:-3px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-border{border:10px solid transparent;left:0;top:0}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-bottom-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-left-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-right-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-top-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-uncropped{position:relative}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-uncropped{top:-10px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-uncropped{left:-10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltipster@4.2.6/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
<span id="tooltipster">tooltip element</span>
<br>
<br>
<button id="add1">hello</button>
<button id="add2">goodbye</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this I figured out a way to solve my problem.

```js
$(function() {
  let tooltip = $("#tooltipster");
  tooltip.tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    side: 'bottom',
    contentAsHTML: true,
    interactive: true
  });
  $("#add1").on("click", function() {
    showTooltip("hello");
  });
  $("#add2").on("click", function() {
    showTooltip("goodbye");
  });
  function showTooltip(text) {
   let instance = tooltip.tooltipster('instance');
    if(instance.status().open) {
     let content = instance.content();
      instance.content(content + "<br>" + text);
    } else {
     instance.content(text).open();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tooltipster-fall,.tooltipster-grow.tooltipster-show{-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1);-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-ms-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-base{display:flex;pointer-events:none;position:absolute}.tooltipster-box{flex:1 1 auto}.tooltipster-content{box-sizing:border-box;max-height:100%;max-width:100%;overflow:auto}.tooltipster-ruler{bottom:0;left:0;overflow:hidden;position:fixed;right:0;top:0;visibility:hidden}.tooltipster-fade{opacity:0;-webkit-transition-property:opacity;-moz-transition-property:opacity;-o-transition-property:opacity;-ms-transition-property:opacity;transition-property:opacity}.tooltipster-fade.tooltipster-show{opacity:1}.tooltipster-grow{-webkit-transform:scale(0,0);-moz-transform:scale(0,0);-o-transform:scale(0,0);-ms-transform:scale(0,0);transform:scale(0,0);-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform;transition-property:transform;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden}.tooltipster-grow.tooltipster-show{-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);-moz-transform:scale(1,1);-o-transform:scale(1,1);-ms-transform:scale(1,1);transform:scale(1,1);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-swing{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:rotateZ(4deg);-moz-transform:rotateZ(4deg);-o-transform:rotateZ(4deg);-ms-transform:rotateZ(4deg);transform:rotateZ(4deg);-webkit-transition-property:-webkit-transform,opacity;-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform;-o-transition-property:-o-transform;-ms-transition-property:-ms-transform;transition-property:transform}.tooltipster-swing.tooltipster-show{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:rotateZ(0);-moz-transform:rotateZ(0);-o-transform:rotateZ(0);-ms-transform:rotateZ(0);transform:rotateZ(0);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,1);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);-ms-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.23,.635,.495,2.4)}.tooltipster-fall{-webkit-transition-property:top;-moz-transition-property:top;-o-transition-property:top;-ms-transition-property:top;transition-property:top;-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-fall.tooltipster-initial{top:0!important}.tooltipster-fall.tooltipster-dying{-webkit-transition-property:all;-moz-transition-property:all;-o-transition-property:all;-ms-transition-property:all;transition-property:all;top:0!important;opacity:0}.tooltipster-slide{-webkit-transition-property:left;-moz-transition-property:left;-o-transition-property:left;-ms-transition-property:left;transition-property:left;-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1);-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-ms-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15);transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(.175,.885,.32,1.15)}.tooltipster-slide.tooltipster-initial{left:-40px!important}.tooltipster-slide.tooltipster-dying{-webkit-transition-property:all;-moz-transition-property:all;-o-transition-property:all;-ms-transition-property:all;transition-property:all;left:0!important;opacity:0}@keyframes tooltipster-fading{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}.tooltipster-update-fade{animation:tooltipster-fading .4s}@keyframes tooltipster-rotating{25%{transform:rotate(-2deg)}75%{transform:rotate(2deg)}100%{transform:rotate(0)}}.tooltipster-update-rotate{animation:tooltipster-rotating .6s}@keyframes tooltipster-scaling{50%{transform:scale(1.1)}100%{transform:scale(1)}}.tooltipster-update-scale{animation:tooltipster-scaling .6s}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-box{background:#565656;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:4px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-box{margin-top:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-box{margin-right:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-box{margin-left:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-box{margin-bottom:8px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-content{color:#fff;line-height:18px;padding:6px 14px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow{overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow{height:10px;margin-left:-10px;top:0;width:20px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow{height:20px;margin-top:-10px;right:0;top:0;width:10px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow{height:20px;margin-top:-10px;left:0;top:0;width:10px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow{bottom:0;height:10px;margin-left:-10px;width:20px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-background,.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-border{height:0;position:absolute;width:0}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-background{border:10px solid transparent}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-bottom-color:#565656;left:0;top:3px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-left-color:#565656;left:-3px;top:0}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-right-color:#565656;left:3px;top:0}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow-background{border-top-color:#565656;left:0;top:-3px}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-border{border:10px solid transparent;left:0;top:0}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-bottom-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-left .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-left-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-right-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-top .tooltipster-arrow-border{border-top-color:#000}.tooltipster-sidetip .tooltipster-arrow-uncropped{position:relative}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-bottom .tooltipster-arrow-uncropped{top:-10px}.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-right .tooltipster-arrow-uncropped{left:-10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltipster@4.2.6/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
<span id="tooltipster">tooltip element</span>
<button id="add1">hello</button>
<button id="add2">goodbye</button>
```